# Keyboard covers input field with Accompanist WebView in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I am using Accompanist WebView and one of my web page has input fields.

When the input field is touched, the UI doesn't change but only keyboard shows up, So, it covers the input field and user can't see what he is typing. like this:

[image]
[image]

This is a bad user experience.

I already set the activity in Androidmanifest.xml to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. But the screen doesn't change.

I expected the screen moves up and keyboard's top is below the input field. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried using BringIntoViewRequester ?
https://blog.canopas.com/keyboard-handling-in-jetpack-compose-all-you-need-to-know-3e6fddd30d9a

Comment: No, And the input field is not kotlin but htm. So, that can't be used. @Pako1